# Removing files added by parent image?

Tags: docker

My Dockerfile extends a parent image that added files (`ADD <src> <dest>`) that I don't need.

Is there a way for me to remove these files from the child image?

Answer (score 0):

Not really usefully.

You *can*

```
RUN rm <dest>
```

and the files won't "show up" when you run the image.  If you do that, though, Docker will keep the base image (unmodified, really just a pointer to that image) plus the data of "delete these directory entries"; the resulting image won't be any smaller if you push it separately from its base image.  You can see this in `docker history` too.